# How to add a decimal point to Javascript Rows, Cols . Vars

Tags: javascript

Hi I have this javascript table, i was wondering whether anyone could help with explaining how to add Decimal point (2) to this. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
//Total Expenditure - Total
document.write ('<tr align="center"><td>' + row14col1var + '<\/td><td>' + row14col2var + '<\/td><td>' + row14col3var + '<\/td><td>' + row14col4var + '<\/td><td>' + row14col5var + '<\/td><td>' + row14col6var + '<\/td><td>' + row14col7var + '<\/td><td>' + row14col8var +'<\/td><td>' + row14col9var + '<\/td><td>' + row14col10var + '<\/td><td>' + row14col11var + '<\/td><td>' + row14col12var + '<\/td><td>' + row14col13var + '<\/td><td>' + row14col14var +'<\/td><\/tr>');

var row14col1var = '<b>Total Expenditure</b>';

var row14col2var = ( Number(row4col2var) + Number(row5col2var) + Number(row6col2var)+   Number(row7col2var)+ Number(row10col2var)+ Number(row11col2var)+ Number(row13col2var));

var row14col3var = ( Number(row4col3var) + Number(row5col3var) + Number(row6col3var) + Number(row7col3var)+ Number(row10col3var)+ Number(row11col3var)+ Number(row13col3var));

var row14col4var = ( Number(row4col4var) + Number(row5col4var) + Number(row6col4var)+ Number(row7col4var)+ Number(row10col4var)+ Number(row11col4var)+ Number(row13col4var));

var row14col5var = ( Number(row4col5var) + Number(row5col5var) + Number(row6col5var)+ Number(row7col5var)+ Number(row10col5var)+ Number(row11col5var)+ Number(row13col5var));

var row14col6var = ( Number(row4col6var) + Number(row5col6var) + Number(row6col6var)+ Number(row7col6var)+ Number(row10col6var)+ Number(row11col6var)+ Number(row13col6var));

var row14col7var = ( Number(row4col7var) + Number(row5col7var) + Number(row6col7var)+ Number(row7col7var)+ Number(row10col7var)+ Number(row11col7var)+ Number(row13col7var));

var row14col8var = ( Number(row4col8var) + Number(row5col8var) + Number(row6col8var)+ Number(row7col8var)+ Number(row10col8var)+ Number(row11col8var)+ Number(row13col8var));

var row14col9var = ( Number(row4col9var) + Number(row5col9var) + Number(row6col9var)+ Number(row7col9var)+ Number(row10col9var)+ Number(row11col9var)+ Number(row13col9var));

var row14col10var = ( Number(row4col10var) + Number(row5col10var) + Number(row6col10var)+ Number(row7col10var)+ Number(row10col10var)+ Number(row11col10var)+ Number(row13col10var));

var row14col11var = ( Number(row4col11var) + Number(row5col11var) + Number(row6col11var)+ Number(row7col11var)+ Number(row10col11var)+ Number(row11col11var)+ Number(row13col11var));

var row14col12var = ( Number(row4col12var) + Number(row5col12var) + Number(row6col12var)+ Number(row7col12var)+ Number(row10col12var)+ Number(row11col12var)+ Number(row13col12var));

var row14col13var = ( Number(row4col13var) + Number(row5col13var) + Number(row6col13var)+ Number(row7col13var)+ Number(row10col13var)+ Number(row11col13var)+ Number(row13col13var));

var row14col14var = ( Number(row4col14var) + Number(row5col14var) + Number(row6col14var)+ Number(row7col14var)+ Number(row10col14var)+ Number(row11col14var)+ Number(row13col14var));
```

Comment: If you're doing it repetitively, you're doing it wrong. That's what computers are for. You probably want to use a combination of arrays and loops to store data, without having to write it all out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to ignore the multitude of design problems with your code and answer your question. If you want to add a decimal point before the last two digits of each number, just use `toFixed(2)`:

```
var row14col2var = (Number(row4col2var) + ... snip ...).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will be revising my code after all comments.